# Pass function 1 as argument to function 2 that will retrieve function 1 result as object

Tags: c#, function

I have two functions, one receives function as parameter and tries to return the result of return of the passed function, second just function that returns object, which i cast later.

```
object function1(Action act) {
    object result = act();
    // do something with result
    return result;
}
object function2() {
    return (object)"string as object";
}
```

And it says that action does not have return type, I'd like to calling it this way:

```
function1(() => function2); // so it'll return "string as object" as object.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change [`Action`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8(v=vs.110).aspx) by [`Func<object>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960(v=vs.110).aspx) since `Action` encapsulates a method but does not return a value.

Another thing to improve is that you might be able to convert function1 to generics so you don't have to deal with casting

```
T function1<T>(Func<T> act)
{
    T result = act();
    // do something with result
    return result;
}

string function2()
{
    return "string as object";
}
```

And then use it like this

```
string myString = function1(function2);
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! (I'll accept as answer after SO stop saying `You can accept an answer in 10 minutes`)